# visual studioでどのくらい有料コンポーネント使っていますか？

Tags: visual-studio

年間ひとりあたりの金額
　初期　約○円
　更新　約○円を知りたいです

状況やスキルにもよるかと思いますが
年間トータル50万円/人はかなり高いのではないかと、、、

Comment: もう少し条件を追加して頂かないと、客観的な回答はしにくそうです（[質問のクローズ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)の可能性もあります）。どのような状況で何をなさりたい上で、といった制限を追記してくださいませんか？　たとえば私は Visual Studio には一切課金をしていませんが、そういった回答を期待されているわけではなさそうです。あわせて、ヘルプページ[「どのような質問は避けるべきですか?」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)の「主観的な質問は建設的であることが期待されます」という部分もご一読くださいませ。

Answer (score 2):

当該コンポーネントが必要な場合に、開発者を雇って自作するか、有料コンポーネントを購入するか、の経営判断でしょう。絶対的な金額のみでは何の判断もできません。